# Setting the progress of a progress bar

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make it so my progress bar increases when the total calories is subtracted from the max calories.. Unfortunately everytime time I click the button to update it the app crashes :/ . I want to be able to grab the calorie values from my SQLite database add those up so I get a total for the calories and then subtract the total calories from the user inputted calorie goal amount from the progress bar.

Here is my code for the progress bar:

```
private void setCalGoals(View view) {
    goalCals = view.findViewById(R.id.addGoalCalories);
    displayCalGoals = view.findViewById(R.id.displayCalorieGoal);
    ProgressBar progressBar = view.findViewById(R.id.trackerBar);

    int allCals = db.addCalories();

    String temp = goalCals.getText().toString().trim();


    displayCalGoals.setText(temp + " calories remaining");

    int max = Integer.parseInt(temp);
    progressBar.setMax(max);

    int totalLeftCals = max - allCals;

   progressBar.setProgress(totalLeftCals);


}
```

Here is the DBHelper class:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "nutrition_table";
    private static final String COL2 = "food";
    private static final String COL3 = "calories";

    DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, TABLE_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase DB) {

        String createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + COL2 + " TEXT, " + COL3 + " TEXT)";

        DB.execSQL(createTable);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase DB, int i, int i1) {

        DB.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(DB);

    }

    public boolean insertData(String food, String calories) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("food", food);
        contentValues.put("calories",calories);

        long res = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);

        if (res == -1) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }

    }

    public Cursor getData() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME, null);
        return cursor;
    }

    public int addCalories() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        int total = 0;

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT SUM(" + COL3 + ") FROM " + TABLE_NAME, null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            total = cursor.getInt(0);
        }

        return total;
    }

}
```

Here is the logcat:

```
    Process: com.example.fitnessbud, PID: 8217
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int com.example.fitnessbud.diary.DatabaseHelper.addCalories()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.fitnessbud.diary.DiaryFragment.setCalGoals(DiaryFragment.java:76)
        at com.example.fitnessbud.diary.DiaryFragment.access$000(DiaryFragment.java:23)
        at com.example.fitnessbud.diary.DiaryFragment$1.onClick(DiaryFragment.java:56)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425)
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Again  (I am just showing this part of the code, in reality I am using a button in my OnCreate to update it). It is kind of like a calorie tracker.

Comment: you should share your logcat so that we can trace your error.

Comment: I have update the question, it has the logcat @RudraRokaya

Comment: Looks like your `addCalories()` is null

Comment: How would I fix that?

Comment: Your `db` DatabseHelper is null. initiliaze it